# JavaScript: Dynamically generated object key

Tags: javascript, object, properties, ecmascript-6, key

```
const cars = [
  {
    'id': 'truck',
    'defaultCategory': 'vehicle'
  }
]

const output = []

Object.keys(cars).map((car) => {
  output.push({
      foo: cars[car].defaultCategory
  })
})

console.log(output)
```

This work fine, however what I want to achieve is so that the newly crated object has structure of `'truck': 'vehicle'`.

So if I replace `push` argument with

```
${cars[car].id}`: cars[car].defaultCategory
```

I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected template string`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cars` is an array. Why use `Object.keys` on it? Just call `map` directly.

Comment: You want `output` to be a plain object (`{}`), not an array.

Comment: How is the output supposed to be structured when there are multiple cars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use map on the array, and not the keys (the indexes) to get an array of objects. For each object use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to set the `id` value as the key:

```js
const cars = [
  {
    'id': 'truck',
    'defaultCategory': 'vehicle'
  }
];

const result = cars.map(({ id, defaultCategory }) => ({ [id]: defaultCategory }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.map()` over your cars `array` and not `Object.keys(cars)`:, we don't use `Object.keys()` with arrays.

This is how should be your code:

```
var output = cars.map(function(car) {
  return {
    [car.id]: car.defaultCategory
  };
});
```

```js
var cars = [{
  'id': 'truck',
  'defaultCategory': 'vehicle'
}];


var output = cars.map(function(car) {
  return {
    [car.id]: car.defaultCategory
  };
});

console.log(output);
```